# calculate shopping cart sale total in laravel and vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i'm developing a shopping cart with laravel and vuejs i'm new to programming. I want to get the total amount of the products in the shopping cart but I don't understand how to do it.
any help is appreciated

I am using vuejs components, in my data element I have a cart that is the one who has the cart with the products.

```
<script >
import Axios from 'axios'
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            csrf: document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
            carrito: [],
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        Axios.get('carrito')
        .then(Response => {this.carrito = Response.data})
    },
}
</script>
```

Inside my template I have a table where it traverses the products with the v-for directive, I would like to have the total in a   but I don't understand how I can do this operation

```
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Producto</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                    <th scope="col">precio</th>
                    <th scope="col">total</th>
                    <th scope="col">accion</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody >
                    <tr v-for="(ProductCart, index) in carrito" :key="index.id">
                        <td>{{ProductCart.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{ProductCart.cantidad}}</td>
                        <td>{{ProductCart.precio}}</td>
                        <td>{{ProductCart.cantidad * ProductCart.precio}}</td>
                        <td> 
                            <form action="" method="post">
                                <input :value="csrf" type="hidden" name="_token" >
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $producto['id'] ?>" >
                                <button  name="btnAccion" value="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"> Remove</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                     <tr>
                        <th colspan="2"></th>
                        <td>
                        <h2>Total</h2>
                        </td>
                        <td align="right">
                        <h3>  </h3> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

so I receive the data

```
{1: {id: "1", name: "Motor 1", cantidad: "1", precio: "20.00"}}
1: {id: "1", name: "Motor 1", cantidad: "1", precio: "20.00"}
cantidad: "1"
id: "1"
name: "Motor 1"
precio: "20.00"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like computed properties would work best in your case. I'm not sure how the data in `carrito` is structured, but assuming it looks something like this:

```
carrito: {
   1: {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Motor 1",
      "cantidad":"1",
      "precio":"20.00"
   }
   ...
}
```

...you would have to loop through `carrito`, take the `precio` times the `cantidad` of each object, and add it to a running total. Here's an example:

```
total: function () {
  let total = 0;
  Object.values(this.carrito).forEach(
    (item) => (total += item.precio * item.cantidad)
  );
  return total;
}
```

`Object.values` returns an array of just the values of `carrito`, which is then iterated through by `.forEach`, and its `precio`s/`cantidad`s are multiplied together, and then then added to the running total, and returned.

`total` would go in `computed: {}`, within your Vue instance. Computed properties are re-evaluated when dependant data changes, so `total` will be reevaluated whenever `carrito` changes. You can then place it wherever you want in the page, like a normal data property:

```
...
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2"></th>
    <td>
      <h2>Total</h2>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
      <h3>{{ total }}</h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
...
```

[image: demo]

Check out the demo [here](https://230vb.csb.app/), (network fetching is simulated, so it takes two seconds to load `carrito`) and its code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-bash-230vb?file=/src/App.vue:1431-1603).

**More info on computed properties:**

- [Computed Properties and Watchers: Vue Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)
- [Computed Properties: Vue Mastery](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/intro-to-vue-js/vue-computed-properties/)

Comment: Thanks for answering I am checking your answer, there are no errors but my result stays at 0

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a sample of `carrito`? Maybe its actual structure is different and so the computed property would have to me modified.

Comment: this error comes out

[Vue warn]: 
Error in render: "TypeError: this.carrito.forEach is not a function"

Comment: Okay, so the problem was that `carrito` is initially an array, but when the data is fetched through axios and `carrito` is updated, it becomes an object. `.forEach` doesn't work on objects, so you can use `Object.values` to just get the values of `carrito` before iterating through them with `.forEach`. I've updated my answer accordingly. It should work fine now, but let me know if it doesn't

Comment: if you notice I corrected it like this
(item) => (total + = parseFloat (item.price * item.quantity))

Comment: Actually, I just discovered after experimenting in the console, when you multiply numbers as strings, they are automatically converted to numbers, so you should be able to remove the all the `parseFloat`s altogether. I had no idea you could do that, but I guess we learn something new every day :D.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a computed property or a method for your component. There you could loop all the items and add each price to a total variable. Then you return the total.

Have a look here: [Vue computed properties](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#basic-example)